# Google Plus Post in PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-plus, google-oauth, google-domain-api

I want to use php to post to google plus. But google plus return "403 forbidden"
I want you to give me a piece of code to make it possible.

This is my auth function :

```
global $client;
$client->setAuthConfig("/home/----");
$client->setRedirectUri("----");


$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write");
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me");
$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
header("Location: $authUrl");
die;
```

And this is my new post function :

```
$client->setAccessToken($token);
$plus = new Google_Service_Plus($client);
$plusdomains = new Google_Service_PlusDomains($client);
$postBody = new Google_Service_PlusDomains_Activity();
$postBody['object']['originalContent'] = 'Happy Monday!';
$result = $plusdomains->activities->insert('me', $postBody);

$result = $plus->people->get('me');

$response->getBody()->write(var_export($result, true));
```

But the result is :

```
{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "forbidden", "message": "Forbidden" } ], "code": 403, "message": "Forbidden" } }
```

As you know ,many sites are now available that send new posts using google oauth to all kind of google plus account ( not only google apps ) ( for example : buffer.com)

Answer (score 1):

[Google Plus domains](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/) is not Google+ the social media website.  This is two separate APIs.

> With the Google+ Domains API, Google Apps customers and ISVs can build
>   custom Google+ functionality and services for people who use Google
>   Apps at college, at work, or at home. Organizations can develop tools
>   to interact with Google+ features such as posts, comments, and
>   circles. These tools let your users share information, reinforce
>   communications, and grow productivity within your organization.

Answer: You are getting an error because you don't appear to have a Google plus domains account.  or the user you are authenticating with does not have access to a Google plus domain.  If you are trying to write to a domain then makes sure that you have the correct user.

**Google+ the social media website:**

The [google+ api](https://developers.google.com/+/web/) is a read only API and does not allow you to programmatically post to the google+ social media website.

> As you know ,many sites are now available that send new posts using google oauth to all kind of google plus account ( not only google apps ) ( for example : buffer.com)

Correction: buffer lets you post to a google plus page / domain account not to the google+ social media website.  I do know now of any application that can post to google+ the social media website besides googles own.  Buffer users domains api allowing Google at work customers, possibly google classroom and google aps to post to the walls of their sites.  This does **not** post to a normal user account on the Google+ social media website.

There is also the [Google pages api](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/pages-signup) which is beta requires special access and probably only for major companies.

Comment: exactly, I want to post to a google plus page - what should I do ? and how does buffer do that ?

Comment: You need to be sure you are connected to your Google domain account. You apparently aren't

Comment: I didn't get you. what should i do for connecting ? What I want is a code that works like this: My client connect his google account to my app and I post a specific text to his google plus page

Comment: This is my Google+ social media page https://plus.google.com/+LindaLawton  you can NOT post to it programmatically.

Comment: How does buffer and ... do that though ? just go to buffer and register and connect your google plus and post what you want

Comment: It doesn't write to a Google+ social media user it writes to a Google plus domain account this is two different websites two different systems

Comment: Buffer does support posting to standard Google+ user profiles but the API is private and general developers can not get access.

Comment: I want to post to Google+ user profile. That's what I wanted. Please Help me how buffer does that or give me a code

Comment: I fact give me a solution so I can post to Google+ profiles with php

Comment: Google+ api is read only it is not possible to post to programmatically post t a users profile.  Google plus domains is for Google At work and Google apps customers it is not a user profile.   Buffer does not post to a normal user Google+ social meda page.  It posts to a google plus domains which is again google at work google class room google apps.   You can not programmatically post to a normal user google+ social media account.